# podspec lint failing with latest Xcode beta

Tags: cocoapods, ios9, podspec, xcode7-beta5

I'm running `pod spec lint --verbose` and get the following output:

```
- Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `Pods-ReachabilitySwift` iOS 8.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-ReachabilitySwift/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-ReachabilitySwift/Pods-ReachabilitySwift.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-ReachabilitySwift/Pods-ReachabilitySwift-umbrella.h`
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 8.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-umbrella.h`
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `../../../private/var/folders/0t/w_3ytpbj79d8s6mtwlf351440000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
2015-08-19 15:35:04.583 ruby[19055:375179] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8190.6/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe2f479d8a0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000105b1a30a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x0000000105b19a97 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000105b19d03 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000105b19c65 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000107ac6754 IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000010bac8bf9 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000010baca77e +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff93b89f44 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

There's an assertion being triggered in `IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()`

The project is compatible with the latest Swift beta, so needs to be build using the latest Xcode-beta command line tools (I've tried setting and re-setting using both `xcode-select` and Xcode's Location Preferences).

Any thought as to what can be done to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3747) , you should change the property `project` to `pod_project`, and run  gem `install xcodeproj` and `pod install` one more time, it should fix the error.